# item radius shape android

Tags: android, xml, styles

Sorry for my English. I can not understand the work with of radius. I need to create a transparent figure in which to store the text.

[image]

Below I have created a figure, but rounded corners at the top-left corner does not work

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <item android:top="-1dp" android:right="-1dp" android:left="-1dp" android:bottom="-1dp">
        <shape>

            <stroke

                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ababb2" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

if i use corners

```
<corners android:radius="1dp"
  android:bottomRightRadius="2dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
  android:topLeftRadius="2dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

a figure rounded everyone, not just the angle that I need

Comment: Such small radiuses won't be noticeable at all. Try 8dp or 16 dp. The angle is 90°, anyway.

Comment: you need only `android:topLeftRadius="2dp"`, get rid of the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Create a xml file in `res/drawable` called `rounded_corner.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" 
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Then, apply the drawable to your view's background like:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/example"
    android:width="wrap_content"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"/>
```